# Add duration to JS setTimeout after the timer is running

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out a way to emulate AS3's Timer class.

If you're not familiar, one of the cool things you can do is add duration to the timer even if it's already running. This functionality has a lot of very nice uses.

Anyone have any thoughts on doing this in js?

Comment: yeah my +1 was because of that also :

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this class, but you can easily create something similar in JavaScript:

```
function Timer(callback, time) {
    this.setTimeout(callback, time);
}

Timer.prototype.setTimeout = function(callback, time) {
    var self = this;
    if(this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    this.finished = false;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.time = time;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
         self.finished = true;
        callback();
    }, time);
    this.start = Date.now();
}

Timer.prototype.add = function(time) {
   if(!this.finished) {
       // add time to time left
       time = this.time - (Date.now() - this.start) + time;
       this.setTimeout(this.callback, time);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var timer = new Timer(function() { // init timer with 5 seconds
    alert('foo');
}, 5000);

timer.add(2000); // add two seconds
```

Answer (score 6):

Clear the timeout, then set a new timeout to the new desired end time.

Answer (score 3):

There you go hope it helps :) just call setInterval with the time you want to have.

Edit: added stop and start in case you want to stop your loop :p

```
function Timer(defaultInterval, callback){
   var interval = defaultInterval;
   var running = true;
   function loop(){
     callback();
     if(running){
        setTimeout(function(){
           loop();
        }, interval);
     }
   }

   loop();
   return {
     setInterval: function(newInterval){
        interval = newInterval;
     },
     stop: function(){
         running = false;
     },
     start: function(){
          if(running===false){
             running = true;
             loop();
          }
     },
     add: function(milliToAdd){
          interval += milliToAdd*1;
     }

   }
}

var myTimer = Timer(250, function() { process code here });
myTimer.setInterval(1000); // sets interval to 1 second
myTimer.stop(); // stops the function
myTimer.start(); // re-starts the loop;
```

Comment: I wrote the object on the fly directly into the answer box so if it has any syntactical error, sorry, but it should be easy to fix :)

Comment: nvm made a quick test and it seems to be running ok :)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the function with another one, and when the timer runs out, test to see if an extra time variable has been set. If it has, start again with the new time, otherwise execute the function.

A [quickly hacked together script](http://jsfiddle.net/u6JhY/) might look like:

```
function test() {
    tim = new timer(function () { alert('hello'); }, 5000);   
}

function extend() {
    if (tim) { tim.addTime(5000); }   
}

function timer(func, time) {
    var self = this,
        execute = function () {
            self.execute()  
        };
    this.func = func;
    this.extraTime = 0;
    setTimeout(execute, time);
};

timer.prototype.execute = function () {
    var self = this,
        execute = function () {
            self.execute()  
        };
    if (this.extraTime) {
        setTimeout(execute, this.extraTime);
        this.extraTime = 0;
    } else {
        this.func();   
    }
};

timer.prototype.addTime = function (time) {
    this.extraTime += time;   
}

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="test()">
<input type="button" value="Extend" onclick="extend()">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function Timer(func, delay) {
  var done = false;
  var callback = function() {
    done = true;
    return func();
  };
  var startTime = Date.now();

  var timeout = setTimeout(callback, delay);

  this.add = function(ms) {
    if (!done) {
      this.cancel();
      delay = delay - (Date.now() - startTime) + ms;
      timeout = setTimeout(callback, delay);
    }
  };

  this.cancel = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  };

  this.immediately = function() {
    if (!done) {
      this.cancel();      
      callback();
    }
  };
};
```

quick test in the console

```
start = Date.now(); 
t = new Timer(function() { console.log(Date.now() - start); }, 1000);
t.add(200);

start = Date.now(); 
t = new Timer(function() { console.log(Date.now() - start); }, 1000000);
t.immediately();
t.immediately();
```

you can add negative times too.

```
start = Date.now(); 
t = new Timer(function() { console.log(Date.now() - start); }, 1000);
t.add(-200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my shot. It keeps track of when the timer was set, and adds the difference to the specified time when you add time.

```
var Timer = {
    set: function(p_function, p_time)
    {
        var d = new Date();
        this.timeStarted = d.getTime();
        this.func = p_function;
        this.timeout = setTimeout(p_function, p_time);
        console.log('timer started at ' + (this.timeStarted / 1000) + ' seconds');
    },
    add: function(p_time)
    {
        var d = new Date(),
            diff = d.getTime() - this.timeStarted,
            newTime = diff + p_time;

        if (this.timeout)
        {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        }

        this.timeout = setTimeout(this.func, newTime);
        this.timeStarted = d.getTime();
    }
};

var myTimer = Object.create(Timer);
myTimer.set(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log('Timer fired at ' + (d.getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function () {
    myTimer.add(5000);
}, 5000);
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gPTfQ/)

Please note that due to overhead of calculation and function calls, this may be a couple milliseconds off.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to throw my little rubber ducky into the pool.

```
var setTimeout2 = function(callback, delay) {
    this.complete = false;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.timeout = false;
    this.dotimeout = function() {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            this.complete = true;
            this.callback.call();
        }, this.delay);
    };
    this.start = Date.now();
    this.add = function(delay) {
        if (!this.complete) {
            this.delay = this.delay - (Date.now() - this.start) + delay;
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.dotimeout.call();
        }
    };
    return this;
};
```

usage

```
var start = Date.now();
var to = setTimeout2(function() {
    document.write(Date.now() - start);
}, 3000);
to.add(3000);
```

similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798680/add-duration-to-js-settimeout-after-the-timer-is-running/7798773#7798773) but a little more compact / no proto

Comment: The problem with your approach is that `this` will refer to `window`, polluting the global namespace... did you mean to write `new setTimeout2...`?

Comment: ahh, i meant to put something different. hold on.